# How to open lightning component as modal from Contact ListView with clicked contacts

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, list-view

I have a lightning component that I want to open as a modal from the ListView of Contacts to send a text message to the checked contacts, exactley how the standard Send Email button works but for text messages instead.

Does anyone know how to do this? When I create a custom ListView button I'm unable to choose lightning component, only visualforce.

Comment: Have you tried using an Action? That should allow you to launch a custom Lightning Component.

Comment: I can't use action in ListViews, only works in Record detail view.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a List view button of type Lightning Component. As a workaround You can try with Visualforce page and embed it in a button of type visualforce . The list view only allows action of type create a record and update record in Lightning.